# Sort by attribute and then by other two attributes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects which each object has the following attributes:

- id (number)
- isBlue (OPTIONAL true or false)
- isRed (OPTIONAL true or false)
- ranking (OPTIONAL number - 1 is more priority than 2 -)
- createdAt (date in string format '2012-02-01')

I want to be able to order the objects in these arrays so that first they appear the ones that are blue, then the ones that are red, and lastly the ones that are not blue or red. Then, within each 'category' by color, I want to order by ranking and then by created at ascending (oldest appear first).

So, I want the blues first, the red second, the other colors last. But then for each color I want to order by raking and created at.

Input example:

```
[ 
{ id: 5, isBlue: false, isRed: true, ranking: 3, createdAt:
'2010-01-20' }, 
{ id: 3, isBlue: false, isRed: true, ranking: 3,
createdAt: '2010-01-23' }, 
{ id: 2, isBlue: false, isRed: true,
ranking: 2, createdAt: '2012-01-23' }, 
{ id: 16, isBlue: false, isRed:
false, ranking: 1, createdAt: '2014-01-23' }, 
{ id: 1, isBlue: true,
isRed: false, ranking: null, createdAt: '2014-01-23' },  
{ id: 10,isBlue: true, isRed: false, ranking: 3, createdAt: '2012-01-23'}
 ]
```

The expected output would be:

```
[
 { id: 10,isBlue: true, isRed: false, ranking: 3, createdAt: '2012-01-23'},
 { id: 1, isBlue: true,
isRed: false, ranking: null, createdAt: '2014-01-23' },
{ id: 2, isBlue: false, isRed: true,
ranking: 2, createdAt: '2012-01-23' },
{ id: 5, isBlue: false, isRed: true, ranking: 3, createdAt:
'2010-01-20' },
{ id: 3, isBlue: false, isRed: true, ranking: 3,
createdAt: '2010-01-23' }, 
{ id: 16, isBlue: false, isRed:
false, ranking: 1, createdAt: '2014-01-23' }, 
]
```

I don't know how to do this order 'by color first' and then by raking and created at within each color group.

Comment: That output is ordered by color but not by ranking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const rows = [ 
{ id: 5, isBlue: false, isRed: true, ranking: 3, createdAt:
'2010-01-20' }, 
{ id: 3, isBlue: false, isRed: true, ranking: 3,
createdAt: '2010-01-23' }, 
{ id: 2, isBlue: false, isRed: true,
ranking: 2, createdAt: '2012-01-23' }, 
{ id: 16, isBlue: false, isRed:
false, ranking: 1, createdAt: '2014-01-23' }, 
{ id: 1, isBlue: true,
isRed: false, ranking: undefined, createdAt: '2014-01-23' },  
{ id: 10,isBlue: true, isRed: false, ranking: 3, createdAt: '2012-01-23'}
 ];
 
 const sorted = rows.sort((a, b) => {
   if( a.isBlue === b.isBlue ) {
     if( a.isRed === b.isRed ) {
       if( a.ranking === b.ranking ) {
         return new Date(a.createdAt) < new Date(b.createdAt) ? -1 : 1;
       }
       return a.ranking < b.ranking ? -1 : 1;
     }
     return b.isRed < a.isRed ? -1 : 1;
   }
   return b.isBlue < a.isBlue ? -1 : 1;
 })
 
 console.log(sorted);
 
 document.write(`ids: ${sorted.map(i => i.id)}`);
```

Comment: I think this does exactly what I want! Thanks. However, is it normal to do these comparisons for booleans: `b.isBlue < a.isBlue` my lint is complaining.

Comment: Is ordered like the output desired, but not as Op said: color, ranking date.

Comment: @HommerSmith yes, booleans are comparable

Comment: Teneff, couldn't we just do `!!b.isRed ? 1 : -1` then? I'm not sure I understand what b.isRed < a.isRed ? -1 : 1 is doing

Comment: @HommerSmith yes, you can, you don't even need the exclamation marks, but I would leave it like this in case of non-boolean comparable values and I find it more readable

Answer (score 1):

you chain sorts from least relevant to most relevant like:

```js
var arr = [{ id: 5, isBlue: false, isRed: true, ranking: 3, createdAt:'2010-01-20' }, 
{ id: 3, isBlue: false, isRed: true, ranking: 3, createdAt: '2010-01-23' }, 
{ id: 2, isBlue: false, isRed: true, ranking: 2, createdAt: '2012-01-23' }, 
{ id: 16, isBlue: false, isRed:false, ranking: 1, createdAt: '2014-01-23' }, 
{ id: 1, isBlue: true, isRed: false, ranking: null, createdAt: '2014-01-23' },  
{ id: 10,isBlue: true, isRed: false, ranking: 3, createdAt: '2012-01-23'} ];


    arr.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(a.createdAt).getTime())
    .sort((a,b) => (b.ranking || 0) - (a.ranking || 0))
    .sort((a,b) => (a.isRed === b.isRed) ? 0 : a.isRed ? -1 : 1)
    .sort((a,b) => (a.isBlue === b.isBlue) ? 0 : a.isBlue ? -1 : 1);
    
    console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This is the answer, color ranking and date

Answer (score 0):

You can use `es6` syntax in replace of `es5` which will be a good choice.

```js
var data = [{
        id: 5,
        isBlue: false,
        isRed: true,
        ranking: 3,
        createdAt: '2010-01-20'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        isBlue: false,
        isRed: true,
        ranking: 3,
        createdAt: '2010-01-23'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        isBlue: false,
        isRed: true,
        ranking: 2,
        createdAt: '2012-01-23'
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        isBlue: false,
        isRed: false,
        ranking: 1,
        createdAt: '2014-01-23'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        isBlue: true,
        isRed: false,
        ranking: null,
        createdAt: '2014-01-23'
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        isBlue: true,
        isRed: false,
        ranking: 3,
        createdAt: '2012-01-23'
    }
];

var obj = {
    isBlue: [],
    isRed: [],
    isNone: []
};
data.forEach(function(val, i) {
    var key = val.isBlue ? "isBlue" : val.isRed ? "isRed" : "isNone";
    obj[key].push(val);
});

function sortValue(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(b.createdAt).getTime();
}
obj.isBlue = obj.isBlue.sort(sortValue);
obj.isRed = obj.isRed.sort(sortValue);
obj.isNone = obj.isNone.sort(sortValue);
var result = [].concat(obj.isBlue).concat(obj.isRed).concat(obj.isNone);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Where are you sorting by the ranking?

Comment: I am sorting individual like `obj.isBlue.sort` and combining in blue,red,and none 
 in series pattern  .

Comment: Yes, but you are not sorting by ranking anywhere within the blue, red and none. You are just sorting by 'createdAt'. I need to sort by 'ranking' and then by 'createdat'. Taking into account that 'ranking' can some times be NULL.